# Can't find google maps fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, tabs

I have been stuck with creating `map` inside a tab. `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)`
`returns null`. Even if I replace it with `getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)`.

I am fairly new to this, so I might have something wrong elsewhere, but I have no idea what it could be.

code

```
public class FragmentMap extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback 
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

to

```
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```